# Upgrade users to new domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I currently have server 2003 as my domain controller. I am planning to upgrade this to 2012, though several articles and videos are available to migrate active directory domain controller from 2003 to 2012. I haven't found anything that explains how can I rejoin users to the new upgraded (2012) domain controller.

I have over 50 computers on the domain, I don't want to manually sit on each computer and re-add each, is there any script or an easier way to do this?

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9OK46bKJ-8

Comment: Do you mean upgrade the machine to 2012? Or upgrade the domain 2012?

Comment: No, another server running 2012, so upgrading the domain to 2012

Comment: You like your company to loose the domain? STandard approach is not to have A domain controller, but a minimum of two - with 50 computers 3 would make sense (dual redundancy). In this case update them one by one. What you try to do is totally unprofessional. There should never by only one domain controller.

Answer (score 5):

When you add the new 2012 domain controller all the Active Directory objects will be replicated automatically to it.  There is no need to re-add anything.  In order to work in 2012 native mode, you will have to move the FSMO roles from the 2003 machine to the 2012 machine and demote the 2003 machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, wouldn't I have to change the Primary DNS of each machine as well as re-add each user individually to the domain again?

Comment: remove the old 2003 machine and give the new machine the same IP, that way you wont have to change DNS.  And no, users are AD objects and will get replicated.